# Equilibrium distribution

Tags: markov-chains

I have learned that irreducible ergodic Markov process has an equilibrium distribution. Does equilibrium distribution exist if the Markov chain is not irreducible? Is the reducible Markov chain reversible?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Markov chain with an absorbing state in state $i$. Then, certainly it is not irreducible; but it has an equilibrium distribution, namely $(0, 0, ...1, 0)$ where the $1$ is in the $i^{th}$ position of the probability vector.

Comment: I understand what you mean, thanks a lot. could you please have a look at the second question?